# localStorage how to keep the effect even if the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to keep the effect on my web page even if the page is refreshed.

**My JS Code:**

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
button.forEach((color) => {
    color.style.backgroundColor = color.getAttribute("data-color");
    color.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const data = color.getAttribute("data-color");
        const root = document.querySelector(":root");
        const styles = {
            "--bs-primary-rgb": data,
        };
        for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
            root.style.setProperty(property, value);
        }
    });
});
```

**What does this code do?**

This code selects all elements with a class of `btn` and then applies a click event listener to each of them. When one of the buttons is clicked, it gets the value of the data-color attribute and sets it as the value of the `--bs-primary-rgb` CSS variable on the root element.

The `querySelectorAll` method returns a static (not live) NodeList of elements that match the specified CSS selector. The `forEach` method is used to iterate over the elements in the NodeList and apply the desired style changes to each element. The `style` property of an element is an object that represents the inline style of the element, and the `setProperty` method is used to set the value of a specific CSS property on that style object.

The `getAttribute` method is used to retrieve the value of the specified attribute of an element. In this case, the value of the `data-color` attribute is retrieved and used to set the value of the `--bs-primary-rgb` CSS variable.

**Check the full app in codepen:**

[Click Here](https://codepen.io/devhoussam1998/pen/zYLGoVE)

Comment: The title of your post says something about local storage, but nowhere in your question you mention anything using local storage? What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage to keep the effect even when the page is refreshed. You save the value (in this case the color) to a `key` (I named yours "color") and when you reload the page the value from the `key` is retrieved, if there is no `key` nothing happens (text stays blue until you start clicking the buttons).

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
    if (localStorage["color"]) {
        const root = document.querySelector(":root");
        const styles = {
            "--bs-primary-rgb": localStorage.getItem("color"),
        };
        for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
            root.style.setProperty(property, value);
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
});

const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

button.forEach((color) => {
    color.style.backgroundColor = color.getAttribute("data-color");
    color.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const data = color.getAttribute("data-color");
        localStorage.setItem("color", data);
        const root = document.querySelector(":root");
        const styles = {
            "--bs-primary-rgb": localStorage.getItem("color"),
        };
        for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
            root.style.setProperty(property, value);
        }
    });
});
```